# Bot framework direct line using POST with JSON data

Tags: botframework

I now use bot framework with Azure functions. 
it now works when the user sends his message its writes it to queue storage then picked up by Azure function and sends it back to the bot with direct line build in Azure function connector.

I want to change the functionality to LogicAppp and return the answer to the user with direct-line with http rest.

I have a key and have a json input that the function got like this:

```
{
  "relatesTo": {
    "user": {
      "id": "default-user",
      "name": "User"
    },
    "bot": {
      "id": "b5023440-b1ce-11e8-9ad8-f5b615a4c6c3",
      "name": "Bot"
    },
    "conversation": {
      "id": "33cd0410-bf46-11e8-a228-a5c7cd21a798|livechat"
    },
    "channelId": "emulator",
    "serviceUrl": "https://0a87dff1.ngrok.io"
  },
  "text": "example",
  "isTrustedServiceUrl": true
}
```

I try to answer the chat using 
https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/conversations/{conversationId}/activitie

I can't make it work, the conversation id looks different, it's like a guid instead of an id.

how can help me with the right POST syntax from the json provided?

Comment: You should provide a [mcve].

Comment: Conversation Ids are generated by the Direct Line connector service (or, the emulator, if you are connected via the emulator).  It looks like you have attempted to generate your own conversation id.  It doesn't work that way.  You should cash an address from a message your bot received from a user, and then when you reply, use the cached address.